# Bootstrap drop down is not expanding

Tags: bootstrap-4, angular6, angular-bootstrap

This is my `HTML` code with bootstrap classes and is using it in `Angular` here the `dropdown` is not expanding, values *Save Data* and *Fetch Data* are not displaying in the browser. But If I use the same code in any online bootstrap workspace it works fine (example W3schools). Here something is not supporting it. I don't understand what I'm missing here. Can anyone please help me out this problem?

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="dropdown open">
           <a  class="dropdown-toggle" role="button"  href="#">Manage <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li > <a href="#"> Save Data</a></li>
              <li> <a href="#"> Fetch Data</a></li>
             </ul>
          </li>
     </ul>
```

And I have added Bootstrap CSS in file angular.json file like in below,

```
 "styles": [
              "src/styles.css",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
            ],
```

I am using `Bootstrap` *v4.1.2.*

Answer (score 0):

You want to make a `header.component.html` file of some sorts where you would have your logo and your `nav` links, that include ***Manage***, ***Save Data***, and ***Fetch Data*** ... I think what you're trying to accomplish goes something like this:

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a routerLink="/" class="navbar-brand">Your App Name</a>
    </div>

    <div class="navbar-default">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li routerLinkActive="active">
          <a routerLink="/recipes">Recipes</a>
        </li>
        <li routerLinkActive="active">
          <a routerLink="/shopping-list">Shopping List</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <ng-template [ngIf]="!authService.isAuthenticated()">
          <li><a routerLink="/signin">Sign In</a></li>
          <li><a routerLink="/signup">Sign Up</a></li>
        </ng-template>
          <li *ngIf="authService.isAuthenticated()"><a style="cursor: pointer;" (click)="onLogout()">Sign Out</a></li>
        <li appDropdown class="dropdown" *ngIf="authService.isAuthenticated()">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" role="button" style="cursor: pointer;">Manage <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a style="cursor: pointer;" (click)="onSaveData()">Save Data</a></li>
            <li><a style="cursor: pointer;" (click)="onFetchData()">Fetch Data</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Under this code, you can find a simple **`Bootstrap 4`** implementation:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Simple Example!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
<!-- Large button groups (default and split) -->
<div class="btn-group">
  <button class="btn btn-success btn-lg dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Save Data
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
<div class="btn-group">
  <button class="btn btn-info btn-lg dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Fetch Data
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu">
    ...
  </div>
</div>


    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```